# Azure Data Factory Copy Data error when exporting from BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, azure-data-factory

I need to export Google Analytics data from the "events" dataset stored on BigQuery.

I'm having ad issue on the Copy Data activity when trying to export data,
the error I'm receiving is the following:

```
Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][BigQuery] (310) Storage API Error: Error thrown in GAvroDataCell:BuildDefaultAvroCell.Invalid BigQueryType specified for copy/move operation. Type is : 0,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.OdbcConnector,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][BigQuery] (310) Storage API Error: Error thrown in GAvroDataCell:BuildDefaultAvroCell.Invalid BigQueryType specified for copy/move operation. Type is : 0,Source=Microsoft ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery,'
```

The pipeline is made of a single Copy Data activity and this is the query I'm executing:

```
    @concat('SELECT
      event_date,
      event_timestamp,
      event_name,
      user_id,
      user_pseudo_id,
      TO_JSON(event_params) as event_params,
      event_previous_timestamp,
      event_value_in_usd,
      event_bundle_sequence_id,
      event_server_timestamp_offset,
      TO_JSON(privacy_info) as privacy_info,
      TO_JSON(user_properties) as user_properties,
      user_first_touch_timestamp,
      TO_JSON(user_ltv) as user_ltv,
      TO_JSON(device) as device,
      TO_JSON(geo) as geo,
      TO_JSON(app_info) as app_info,
      TO_JSON(traffic_source) as traffic_source,
      TO_JSON(stream_id) as stream_id,
      TO_JSON(platform) as platform,
      TO_JSON(event_dimensions) as event_dimensions,
      TO_JSON(ecommerce) as ecommerce,
      TO_JSON(items) as items
    FROM `xxxxxxxproject-bigquery.analytics_310106672.events_2023*`'
    )
```

The linked service of type "BigQuery" is working since the "test connection" results with "ok", and also the dataset is ok because "preview data" returns data from the remote dataset.

The "preview data" on the Copy Data activity gives error like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSVnN.png)

I've found that it has something to do with the widlcard "*" in the tablename. The copy data works when I construct a dynamic query like this:

```
@concat('SELECT <fields>
FROM `xxxxxxxproject-bigquery.analytics_310106672.events_', '20230520`')
```

But this one is not working:

```
@concat('SELECT <fields>
FROM `xxxxxxxproject-bigquery.analytics_310106672.events_', '202305', '*', '`')
```

I'm investigating on google source side.

Comment: `Invalid BigQueryType specified for copy/move operation` can you provide your query and pipeline image for better understanding?

Comment: Hello @RakeshGovindula I added the query in the body of the question. Thank for your time

Comment: Did you tried the preview of source in copy activity with the above query? and also is the above query working fine in Big Query? Provide copy activity image if possible.

Comment: The query works fine on BigQuery, I've added a screenshot of the copy activity

Comment: You had a single query, Instead of using concat function, did you directlt given the query in it? Is it resulting same?

Comment: I've made a little step forward. It looks like it's something to do with the backtick.

Comment: yeah based on your copy activity image, it must be with the query as the source preview fails.

Comment: I haven't yet found any documented restriction in exporting data from BigQuery API using wildcards for table names. I'm changing the strategy so to export each table one by one.

thank you for you support @RakeshGovindula

Comment: what is your destination?

Comment: I think wild card table names in ADF script might not be supported currently. So better to use the strategy of listing out tables and looping them in ADF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, Currently ADF might not support the wildcard table selection like Big Query queries and that is the reason for your error.

The workaround for your requirement can be list out all the tables from the source using the below query with a Lookup activity.

```
SELECT table_name FROM `<project>`.<dataset_id>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```

If you want, you can filter this output array with `starts_with()` using filter activity.

Then Give this output array to a ForEach activity.

[image]

Inside **ForEach**, use copy activity and give `@item().table_name` for both source dataset and sink dataset(use dataset parameters here).

If you are copying data to ADLS copy each table to a temporary table of a folder and after ForEach, use another copy activity and use wild card file path in the source. In the sink of the copy activity, use **merge** copy type and these files will be saved to single file.